# &"warning: GDB: Failed to set controlling terminal: Operation not permitted\n"

Tags: c, linux, debugging, visual-studio-code

I'm currently using vscode on ubuntu to write and debug a simple c program.
I've updated gdb to the newest version(9.2-0ubuntu1~20.04.1). Whenever I click the debug button a "Permission Denied" error is shown.

[Here's a screenshot of the error message](https://i.stack.imgur.com/jW0qp.jpg)

How do I resolve this error so that I can debug my C program with GDB and VSCode? I would appreciate it. The problem has bothered me for days and I can't figure it out myself.

This code snippet below is my launch.json file.

```
// Use IntelliSense to learn about possible attributes.
// Hover to view descriptions of existing attributes.
// For more information, visit: https://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?linkid=830387
"version": "0.2.0",
"configurations": [
    {
        "name": "(gdb) Launch",
        "type": "cppdbg",
        "request": "launch",
        "program": "${workspaceFolder}/a.out",
        "args": [],
        "stopAtEntry": false,
        "cwd": "${fileDirname}",
        "environment": [],
        "externalConsole": false,
        "MIMode": "gdb",
        "setupCommands": [
            {
                "description": "Enable pretty-printing for gdb",
                "text": "-enable-pretty-printing",
                "ignoreFailures": true
            },
            {
                "description": "Set Disassembly Flavor to Intel",
                "text": "-gdb-set disassembly-flavor intel",
                "ignoreFailures": true
            }
        ]
    }
]
```

}

Comment: Are you sure a.out is indeed existing and an executable program?